# Magento: Need to get Catalog_Product_Option ID for product options

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a product that has several options. All of which are to be duplicated to other products. The design is highly customized so I need to pass the options within code itself.

Setting them up isn’t the issue, I have figured that out. The issue is that I only have it working on 1 product with the options that are passed in HTML. What I am looking for is the PHP to get certain option values so that it configures correctly.

```
<dl>            
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Size</label></dt>
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="options[3]" id="select_3" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title=""  onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
        <option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="7"  price="1" >a +$1.00</option>
        <option value="8"  price="2" >b +$2.00</option>
        <option value="9"  price="3" >c +$3.00</option>
        </select>                                
      </div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

What I need is the PHP to get the value from the database for

```
name="options[3]"

id="select_3"
```

I can see these inside the database, but I don't know how to pull them out and echo them in the code.

I guess I would need a code that first recognizes the product, then based on that will echo the values and ids needed for the options.

I’ve scoured the internet looking for an answer but no luck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);    
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) { 
$o->getValues();
}
```

from this you can find all options of product